# SQLITE Replace Column IDs with NAMES from SEPERATE TABLE in same DB

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a sqlite database avalible here => https://www.dropbox.com/s/9cn093ns3ot2cik/drinks.db?dl=0

I'm trying to show ( or replace?) the `drinks.glass_id` with its proper name from `glasses.name`

I have tried

```
select drinks._id DID, 
       drinks.glass_id GID,
       glasses.name GNAME,
       glasses._id GIDD 
from drinks DRNKS
     join glasses GLS
     on drinks.glass_id = glasses._id
```

What is wrong??
I have spent several hours looking this up.
I have read these links and still cant figure it out.

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/242166-sql-query-help-convert-category-id-to-the-text-name

[Replacing a pulled SQL ID value with its name from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123253/replacing-a-pulled-sql-id-value-with-its-name-from-another-table)

[How to replace fetched values with another column while querying with SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771648/how-to-replace-fetched-values-with-another-column-while-querying-with-sql-server)

[how to get name from another table with matching id in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193986/how-to-get-name-from-another-table-with-matching-id-in-another-table)

Comment: What is wrong? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

If you specify an alias for your tables then you have to use it everywhere

```
select d._id DID, 
       d.glass_id GID,
       g.name GNAME,
       g._id GIDD 
from drinks d
join glasses g on d.glass_id = g._id
```

Comment: That didn't work. `Error: near "join": syntax error`

Comment: The one you just posted.

Comment: Im using database browser portable. Heres my personal copy Im using
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mlpflj54zga6rd6/DatabaseBrowserPortable.rar?dl=0